# create a session if does not exists in python requests

Tags: python, session

Hi i am able to logged in using python requests.

```
ses = requests.session()
datas = {'username':'admin','password':'abc'}
req = ses.post('http://example.com/login/', data=datas)
```

However, i now need to establish session or need to logged in only if its not logged in. I tried using:

```
if not ses:
    ses = requests.session()
    datas = {'username':'admin','password':'abc'}
    req = ses.post('http://example.com/login/', data=datas)
```

but it didn't worked. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: *but it didn't worked* is not a problem description, really. How did it not work? Do you have a wider context that you can store the session object *on*? How often are you creating a session?

Comment: this code in a separate function. I need to call this function if there is no session.

Comment: That is clear as mud; where would you *store* the session if you wanted to reuse it?

Comment: inside the session object of the requests

Answer (score 0):

That exact code won't work because `ses` is used before it's defined. Instead, try:

```
ses = None

def get_ses():
    global ses
    if ses is not None:
        ses = requests.session()
    return ses

ses = get_ses()
datas = {'username':'admin','password':'abc'}
req = ses.post('http://example.com/login/', data=datas)
```

This isn't very nice because it uses a global variable. Preserving state for use between functions is exactly what objects are for, so it should be a class:

```
class SessionFactory(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.ses = None

    def get(self):
        if self.ses is None:
            self.ses = requests.session()
            return self.ses

 sf = SessionFactory()
 ses = sf.get()
 datas = {'username':'admin','password':'abc'}
 req = ses.post('http://example.com/login/', data=datas)
```

Comment: This if statement will satisfy for ever. I don't think its a good solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the session as:

```
def login_website(username, password):
    session.post(LOGIN_URL, data=form, params=params)
    return session_or_None

session = login_website(username, password)

if session is None:
    print("No Session Found.")
else:
    print("Session Found!")
```